# VBA If with two conditions

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, foreach

I am trying to write a vba, which checks if column A is a specific string and column B is a specific string. If it's true, the cell in Column B should change its value to the string from column A. I think I am far away from the correct code.

```
Sub NomenklaturDatum()

Dim cell As Range
Dim rng As Range

For Each cell In rng:

    if cell.Value in rng("J5:J175") = "2019" and cell.Value in rng("D5:D175") = ("Backlog") Then:

        cell.Value in rng("J5:J175") = "Backlog"

    End If

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You talk about column A and B, but you check J and D (even if the code is incorrect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something within these lines

```
Sub NomenklaturDatum()

    Dim cl As Range

    For Each cl In Range("J5:J175")
        If cl.Offset(0, -6).Value = "Backlog" And cl.Value = "2019" Then
            cl.Value = "Backlog"
        End If
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Of course, you can make it more versatile - pass range as argument, or detect the last row, etc.